# Какая тема используется на сайте Android Developers?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, themes

На сайте [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com) есть вставки с кодом (довольно красивые):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задавшись целью поставить в свою среду разработки такую же тему, я провёл много времени и просмотрел кучу плагинов, но так и не нашёл её.

Пожалуйста, если она существует, подскажите как она называется! Очень уж хочется чтобы мой код был в таких же красивых цветах)

Comment: почему вы думаете, что это именно какая-то "тема"? Можете просто пойти в настройки с настроить любые цвета, какие вам нравятся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В разделе values>colors добавьте цвета которые хотите использовать в своем приложение. Потом если хотите указать какой то цвет фону или чему либо другому добавьте строку  background="@colors/name_colors" и будет вам щастье!